# css border-image and background image masking

Tags: html, css, image

please check my example in this [jsfidle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/p9CYP/).

```
<div class="border background" style="width:200px; height:200px"> </div>
.border
{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 17px 7px 5px 10px;
  -o-border-image:url(image1)  17 7 5 10 repeat;
  -moz-border-image: url(image1)  17 7 5 10 repeat;
  border-image: url(image1) 17 7 5 10 fill repeat;

}
.background
{
  content: url(image2);
}
```

I have an image located inside a border-image,

the outside border-image has a shape and the image inside is square,

I want the image to fill the entire border of the border-image (like masking the inner image).

how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question, and add whatever code needed to the body, rather than linking it to elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```
 <div class="border" style="width:200px; height:200px">
    <div class="background" style="width:204px; height:215px;"></div> 
 </div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/p9CYP/4/)

Comment: no.. I want the image to fit to the outer border shape including the rectangle shape on the left upper corner

Comment: In that case, why you need border image??

Comment: because without border image how would I make that shape? (on top left corner)

Comment: I want that rectangle shape on the corner

Comment: rectangle?? we have triangle only on the corner.

Comment: But in your background-image itself it is not in exactly left corner. If want the image only align exactly in that place then check this http://jsfiddle.net/p9CYP/6/